# strstr in switch statements

Tags: c++, switch-statement, strstr

I'm making a program that lets user enter a string then program searches various words in the string using `strstr` function, then calls different functions according to which word is found.I decided to use switch statements to check which words are present.I made a prototype program as:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "This is a string.";
    char str1[] = "is";
    int num = strstr(str, str1);

    switch(num) {
        case 0:
            cout<<"Str1 is present";
            break;
        case -1:
            cout<<"str1 is absent";
            break;
    }
}
```

It's gimme the error:

> invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: isn't `strstr` returns `NULL` on fail? Just check `if (num)`

Comment: So, in summary what you do wrong is you fail to RTFM. A good way to avoid that is, in SO question, add manual reference link to problematic item, here for example a good google hit of [man strstr](https://www.google.com/search?q=man+strstr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strstr` returns a `char*` or `const char*`

Have a read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

```
char str1 = "This is a string.";
char str2 = "is";
char* result = strstr(str1, str2);
if (result == NULL)
{
    cout<<"str1 is absent";
}
// etc
```

Comment: So how can I use it with switch statements

Comment: There is only two conditions, why do you need a switch statement.

Comment: I said it is just a prototype, in actual program there will be several conditions. If I use strstr to search for is and string so what will be the syntax for that in switch statement?

Comment: @hyde switch works only for char or int. char * would result in error.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Ahm, you're right, C switch does not allow pointers. So it's not just bad practice, it just won't compile :)